# In simulated console, echo only on Enter

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, console, console-application, windows-console

I'm running a command line process in a Windows window, with redirected stdin/stdout/stderr. The process might be interactive, so I need to pass the keyboard input to it. I do so by writing typed bytes to the process' `StandardInput`, with `AutoFlush=true`.

I'm testing on cmd.exe. I can see that cmd receives the input - if I type "dir[Enter]", the command is executed as expected. The characters are passed to StandardInput exactly when they're typed, I've checked.

**However, here's the weirdness: the typed characters are only echoed back to the process' stdout when I press Enter.**

This looks like a flushing issue, but I can't modify cmd's behavior; I can't force it to flush after every byte.

Here's the KeyPressed handler:

```
    Process m_Proc;

    //...

    private void OnConsoleKey(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (m_Proc != null && !m_Proc.HasExited)
        {
            char c = e.KeyChar;
            if (c == '\r')
                m_Proc.StandardInput.Write("\r\n"); //Enter key delivered as CR, no LF
            else
                m_Proc.StandardInput.Write(c);
            m_Proc.StandardInput.Flush();
        }
    }
```

I am processing stdout on per-byte basis, not on per-line basis, like this:

```
    m_Proc.Start();
    new Thread(StreamReaderProc).Start(m_Proc.StandardOutput);

    //...

    private void StreamReaderProc(object o)
    {
        StreamReader sr = o as StreamReader;
        for (; ; )
        {
            int c = sr.Read();
            if (c == -1) //End of file - that means the process quit
                break;
            else
                BeginInvoke(new Action<char>(LogChar), (char)c);  //Can't modify the log contents from a worker thread
        }
    }
```

Any idea what's the matter here?

Comment: Not releated to your problem but are you sure the enter key just sends a `\r` and does not raise OnConsoleKey twice, once with `\r` once with `\n`. It just seems really weird that it sends a carrage return instead of a line feed or sending both.

Comment: No, only CR. I've checked.

Comment: are you debugging in Visual studio? Did you try with `Release` compilation?